# Bootstrap grid problems

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Hey so Im new to boostrap 3 and Im trying to recreate a site as practice. I need to find a way to add 3 rows with (various col-md*sizes) of boxes to the left and a large picture to the right that stretch to the bottom of the page without disturbing my other boxes/rows that are on the left side. Ive looked up multiple ways to do this but if someone out there can provide a code on how this is possible with an explanation that would help me with this project and many more to come. If you go to the link below, the example is the first one with the guy wearing the yellow rain coat:
http://www.geckoandfly.com/13189/7-impressive-online-cv-resume-template-successful-job-hunting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you show you code will be a bit easier but ... the code should look something like this

```
<div class="row col-lg-12">

<div class="col-lg-8 leftSide">
 <!--This is the left side of that"div"and here you can add rows as much as you want-->
  <row>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"><div>
  </row>

   <row>
    <div class="col-lg-7"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-5"><div>
  </row>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-8 right side">
   <!--The image part is here-->
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Im having trouble uploading my code, so pretty much all I had to do was add a <div class='col-md-12' from the start and that should pretty much open everything up? uggggh

Comment: and also can you just get away with putting  just <row> on there instead of the whole div class blah blah nonsense?